# PyTorch: Inconsistent behavior in torch.arange

Tags: arrays, pytorch

I'm using Google Colab and when I run the following code:

```
from torch import tensor, arange

print( arange(0.0, 1.2, 0.2) )
print( arange(tensor(0.0), tensor(1.2), tensor(0.2)) )
```

I get the output:

```
tensor([0.0000, 0.2000, 0.4000, 0.6000, 0.8000, 1.0000])
tensor([0.0000, 0.2000, 0.4000, 0.6000, 0.8000, 1.0000, 1.2000])
```

This discrepancy also occurs with `arange(0.0,1.1,0.1)` but there is no discrepancy with `arange(0.0,1.5,0.5)`.

Why does seemingly similar code give different results, and how can I anticipate when this will occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a numerical precision issue :(

By default, Python stores floating point numbers in double precision (aka `float64`), while PyTorch uses `float32` by default.

If you try:

```py
tensor(1.2).item()
tensor(1.2).dtype  # torch.float32
```

you'll get `1.2000000476837158`, and `arange` with that number will be different from the one with `1.2`. In this specific case, if you try:

```py
import torch
from torch import tensor, arange

print(arange(tensor(0.0), tensor(1.2, dtype=torch.float64), tensor(0.2)))
```

you'll get what you expect, however even `float64` will have some precision issue eventually. Anyway, as Python also uses double precision, you won't have this problem converting a scalar back and forth in this case.

I'm not sure if you can anticipate it.